# is there a way to configure both tailwind and typescript in nextjs while initializing?

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss my-project

this only seems to congifure tailwind

```
npx create-next-app -ts
```

this only configure typescript

npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss my-project  -ts

this dosent seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid there is no such template right now for both of this things. I suggest you to init both templates then manually copy needed files (`tailwind.config`, `postcss.config` and etc.) from tailwind folder to typescript folder.

Answer (score 0):

To add tailwind css you just need to follow few steps

Step 1 : Install Dependencies

```
npm install tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init
```

Step 2 : Configure postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

Step 3 : Configure tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Step 4 : Add this styles to css file

```
/* styles/globals.css */

@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

It's Done.

For detail understanding check this
https://romik-mk.medium.com/configure-tailwind-css-in-next-js-c91e2c859463